# About env file extension

Tags: shell, env

now, i want to know about env file extension. what is env file type? How to encrypt my file with env file type. And, How to open env file? Can you open env file type within shell script coding? eg. `#!/bin/bash source myfile.env`

Comment: Are you sure that there's anything special about this file? Have you tried opening it in a text editor to examine its contents? What operating system are you using? In many systems, file extensions are arbitrary and are only used to indicate the purpose of a file - for example, a file ending in `.env` might be used to set some environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The ENV file extension is primarily associated with Adobe Acrobat and Acrobat Reader files. An ENV file holds spelling and format setting information.

Acrobat lets you capture a document and then view or share it in its original format and appearance. To view an Acrobat document, which is called a Portable Document Format  (PDF) file, you need Acrobat Reader.

The ENV file extension is also associated with Creatacard envelope project Broderbund files, HP-95 Environment files, Motocross Madness track files, WordPerfect for Windows environment files and WOPR enveloper macro files.

Comment: ⇒　which file type can change to env file type? How to change myfile into env file type?